# Jakarta Dsn - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am reading mails from my inbox using javamail with spring boot, which is successful. But when i added dsn to my maven which is used for parsing and creating messages containing Delivery Status Notifications, i started having error messages when it's about to read a failed delivery mail from my mail server but if the mail is not a failed one it will read it except the failed mail.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsn</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

this is the error i keep getting

```
2021-11-10 10:59:11.195 ERROR 6420 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/activation/DataContentHandler
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:595)
at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:555)
at javax.activation.CommandMap.createDataContentHandler(CommandMap.java:205)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:597)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:524)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1484)
at org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser.parse(MimeMessageParser.java:194)
at org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser.parse(MimeMessageParser.java:95)
at org.cpa.churchms.mail.ProcessInboxMail.extractMail(ProcessInboxMail.java:152)
at org.cpa.churchms.mail.ProcessInboxMail.lambda$0(ProcessInboxMail.java:111)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at org.cpa.churchms.mail.ProcessInboxMail.handleInboxMail(ProcessInboxMail.java:110)
at org.cpa.churchms.config.MailConfig$1.handleMessage(MailConfig.java:93)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:59)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:475)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:461)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 47 more
```

i added a lower version of the dsn to my maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsn</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

i still had the same error. I added Jakarta Activation

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Yet no improvement. I changed to this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Still the same error. Please i need help